# what's the difference between mon() and on() in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Could anyone please explain the difference between `mon()` and `on()` in ExtJS?

Comment: What does the documentation say about `mon()`? What about `on()`? How are they different?

Comment: @pst sorry,i tried to look for it in the docs and couldnt find it

Answer (score 7):

Well, if you want to avoid memory leaks then you use **mon** instead of **on** to bind events. 
For example:

```
var p = new Ext.Panel({
     renderTo:Ext.getBody()
    ,title:'Panel with a listener on the body'
    ,beforeDestroy:function() {
        this.body.un('click', handler);
    }
});
```

If you add listeners as inline function, like:

```
p.on('click', function() {alert('You clicked my body')});
```

then it not possible to remove this listener **selectively**. But, if you use **mon** for it, then the listener is automatically removed by ExtJs on panel destroy.

Comment: For what it's worth, [here's](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153565-ExtJS-Performance-Best-Practices#6) a tangential post from the forum regarding event handling.

Answer (score 1):

**mon** - Adds listeners to any Observable object (or Ext.Element) which are automatically removed when this Component is destroyed.

**on** - Appends an event handler to an observable object

See:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext-method-on

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-mon